# Adding case condition in select clause gives //either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause// error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have defined my select query like;

```
SELECT  Day(Date) as Day, 
        ... 
        Case
            when (SUM(GallonsPumped)*0.01 +130 <ABS(Sum(DailyVar))) Then 'Fail'
            Else 'pass'
        End as result,
        ....
FROM  [dbo].[zzz]
WHERE date >='2019-09-12' and date<='2019-10-09' and SiteCode='0209365' and CompanyId = 67   
order by  CAST(Date AS Date) asc
```

But getting;

> Column 'tablezzz.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This occurs due to me Case statement. If I remove that, my select query works fine. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to post the complete query. May be the error is related to something else not with your case statement.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need  a group by for the columns not involved in aggregation function

so assuming you have columns Day, col1, col2, col3 not involved  in aggreagtion you need  agroup by with  GROUP BY Day(Date), col1, col2, col3

```
  SELECT  Day(Date) as Day, 
        col1, 
        col2,

        Case
            when (SUM(GallonsPumped)*0.01 +130 <ABS(Sum(DailyVar))) Then 'Fail'
            Else 'pass'
        End as result,
        col3
FROM  [dbo].[zzz]
WHERE date >='2019-09-12' and date<='2019-10-09' and SiteCode='0209365' and CompanyId = 67   
GROUP BY Day(Date), col1, col2, col3 
order by  CAST(Date AS Date) asc
```